# How to change the message in checkedmultiSelect widget in dojo?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

Im using the dojo widget CheckedMultiSelect,how to change the message "0 items(s) selected" to some other message(Ex:Prefrences).

```
var select =   new CheckedMultiSelect({
        dropDown: true,
        labelText: 'States',
        multiple: true,
        name: 'state',
        onChange: getValues,
        required: true
    }, "stateSelect");
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more it unclear what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm using this CheckedMultiSelect widget as in this jsfiddler link http://jsfiddle.net/down_quark/cNATk/
By default the message on MENU is shown as "0 items(s) selected"..
 I want to change that message to something else..

Comment: And also im getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalidMessage' of undefined..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The label text is set via Dojo's `i18n` system. The simplest way to override it for an individual select box is to directly modify the resource used to set the label:

```
select._nlsResources.multiSelectLabelText = 'foo';
```

You can globally modify the resource by using a loader map to override the nls resource used for CheckBoxMultiSelect widgets. Modify your `dojoConfig` (or set one up) before loading `dojo.js`:

```
<script>
    var dojoConfig = {
        // ...
        map: {
            '*': {
                'dojox/form/nls/CheckedMultiSelect': 'myApp/someModule'
            }
        },
        // ...
    }
</script>
<script src="wherever/dojo.js"></script>
```

Module `myApp/someModule` should follow the format of a Dojo nls resource, and contain the same keys under `root` as the original CheckedMultiSelect nls file:

```
define({
    root: {
        multiSelectLabelText: 'foo',
        // ...
    }
});
```